# Find file generated 1 day ago and the name has pattern "performance-team(A/B/C-(yesterday's date)"

Tags: debian, cron, ssmtp

Trying to find how to regularly find any file generated 1 day ago and the name has pattern "performance-team(A/B/C)-(yesterday's date)". And then email it to certain mail-address from Tuesday to Sunday at 2 am?

My current script "testScript1.sh" is as follows:

```
arr=()
#do not know how to include a day before date and team names : A,B or C
arr=($(find /root/Desktop/fileName -maxdepth 1 -name "performance-team*.txt" -mtime 0))

for i in "${arr[@]}"
 do
    echo -e "to:email@email.com\nSubject:performance latest\n"|(cat - && uuencode $i)|/usr/sbin/ssmtp email@email.com
```

In crontab my command is

```
0 2 * * 2-7 /bin/sh /root/Desktop/fileName/testScript1.sh
```

Above testScript1.sh script is not giving me exact thing. I also cannot run it regularly in crontab. Please help.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

use `-d` option of date e.g.

```
date -d yesterday
```

for instance

```
> date
Mon Oct 17 07:36:10 CEST 2016
> date -d yesterday
Sun Oct 16 07:36:17 CEST 2016
```

you can also use +% format

```
date -d yesterday +%A-%d-%B
```

> Sunday-16-October

see `man date`